# Dynamically load class from maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I have maven dependency with scope set to runtime and from another module I try loading a class using Class.forName("com.example.something.full.path") and I see ClassNotFoundException.  I have module B dependent on module A. I am trying to load a class from A within B. The class where I am trying to do Class.forName is initialized using Spring. I can see that jar (module A) is in the classpath of B, isn't that enough?

Adding more details:

I am trying to test it using Eclipse.
In the end it must be working as part of a webapp or any standalone java process.

EDIT:

Sorry, I was not clear in my description of the problem. I was trying to load an inner class dynamically. When I did Class.forName("com.example.myclass$innerclass") it worked.

Comment: We need more detail than this in order to help you. Are you trying to run this test in an IDE? If so which one?

Comment: "From another module"? You mean a different module from where you have the dependency defined? That won't work out too well.

Comment: @RyanStewart I have module B dependent on module A. I am trying to load a class from A within B.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check your maven config is to run your main class with maven:

```
mvn compile exec:java -D exec.mainClass=<your main class>
```

That will tell you truly whether you have a problem with your dependency. If you get a CNFE like that, then almost certainly there's no class with the name you specified in the jar you're depending on.